# SVG Path is not displaying in UI but its showing <path> as 0x0 in inspect element

Tags: svg

I am creating SVG path in typescript but SVG path is not displaying in the web page but in inspect element, the elements are showing. In the inspect element, svg's path is showing size as 0x0. My code is below. Please help me.

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewbox="-100 -100 500 500" class="svgStyle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: absolute;" width="300px" height="300px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<path id="arc2" fill="none" stroke="#F1F1F1" stroke-width="40" stroke-linecap="round" d="M 234.8528137423857 234.8528137423857 A 120 120 0 1 0 65.14718625761428 234.8528137423857"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your path has no `d` attribute

Comment: The path has no `d` element and therefore is empty. So a size of 0 by 0 makes perfect sense.

Comment: I see you edited your question and the svg path has now a `d` attribute. The path as it is is now displaying correctly. If you are creating this path dynamically I suspect you are creating it using the  `createElement` method. In SVG, in order to create a new element you have to use the [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) method. Also if you only set the `d` attribute in JS you need to use the [setAttributeNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS) method.